# RollingFileAppender properties not found (WARN No such property [rollingPolicy]) - jboss eap 6

Tags: java, apache, logging, jboss

I would appreciate your assistance in the following issue:
We are currently trying to use the org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender along with the below sample configuration in log4j.properties file in our code:

```
     log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
     log4j.appender.app.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
     log4j.appender.app.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=${logs.applications.dir}/file.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
     log4j.appender.app.File=${logs.applications.dir}/file.log
     log4j.appender.app.Threshold=DEBUG
     log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
     log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}  %-5p - %m%n
```

The errors exposed in the console are of the below type:

```
     ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) log4j:WARN No such property [rollingPolicy] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
```

Similar errors are exposed when we use the triggeringPolicy.
Then again, when we replace the appender with the following:

```
     org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
```

we receive errors that the class is not found and others related to the PropertyConfigurator we use in our code.

We have been looking into the use of xml too, as suggested in the below link:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html

Considering this last statement, we were wondering whether it is actually mandatory to re-configure our logger through a log4j.xml and somehow make our code to look there prior to the properties file (and/ or fully redirect it to the xml) or the errors are related to some other configuration issue.

Any assistance/ recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: *.jars used in the process:

```
     log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1 (or)
     log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2
```

and

```
     apache-log4j-extras-1.0.jar (or)
     apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? please do share the solution.